# Need help creating a radial chart wrapped around iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe, graph

I need help creating an earth with graph wrapped around.

[I want it look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pw3wd.png)

[How it looks like on the website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zLN5.png)

The graph is rendered by using this div & chartjs:

```
<div id="canvas-holder" style="width:100%">
    <canvas id="chart-area" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
</div>
```

The code of earth iframe is:

```
<div style="margin: 0 auto;background:transparent;width:400px;height:400px">
    <iframe style="margin: 0 auto;align:center;border-radius:50%" src="https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/gltf_embed/2393" width="400px" height="400px" frameborder="0" >
    </iframe>
</div>
```

Big thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Use position absolute to position the earth on top of the graph.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.graph {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 8px solid red;
}

.earth {
  position: absolute;
  left: 18px; top: 18px;
  width: 180px; height: 180px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="graph"></div>
  <div class="earth"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I applied your code and made it look like this. Please see the link http://netzero.ga/calculator/

Please send me updated code to keep in center always